# List.Remove(Item item) does not behave as expected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and trying remove duplicates from a List using a dictionary key/value pair.

**ISSUE:**
When the code is run, **IF** there are duplicates, the first item in the list is deleted and NOT the specific item as "*List.Remove(Item item)*" should.

```
public static Dictionary<string, Farm> farmDict = new Dictionary<string, Farm>();
public static List<Farm> farmBuildingsList = new List<Farm>();

public static void UpdateList<T>(List<T> list, Dictionary<string, T> dict, string ID, T resBuilding) where T : ResourceBuildings, new()
    {
        T obj = new T()
        {
            ID = resBuilding.ID,
            hourlyIncome = resBuilding.hourlyIncome,
            baseHour = resBuilding.baseHour,
            incomeIncrement = resBuilding.incomeIncrement,
            totalSupply = resBuilding.totalSupply
        };

        if (dict.ContainsKey(ID))
        {
            dict[ID] = obj;
            list.Remove(dict[ID]);
            list.Add(dict[ID]);
        }
        else
        {
            dict.Add(obj.ID, obj);
            list.Add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Using Debug.Logs at the if statement, `dict[ID]` is null, but dict[ID].ID (and all the properties) contains the correct value, so the entire thing is not null. I am not sure if this is the issue, but I've asked for a solution on fixing Object.name within gamedev.stackexchange.

I've read on more appropriate ways (https://www.dotnetperls.com/duplicates and other stackoverflow posts) to remove duplicates using Linq and hashsets, but I can't figure out how to override Equals and HashCode functions.

Comment: That's exactly what should happen when you call `Remove` on a `List<T>`.  The documentation even states it outright: "Removes the first occurrence of a specific object from the List(Of T)". You would need to find the index of the item and call `RemoveAt` instead. You can try getting the index of the key from the `Keys` collection of the `Dictionary` but that's not an `IList` so it has no `IndexOf` method and I'm not sure whether you'll get consistent ordering.

Comment: It seems to me that you should simply do away with the `List` altogether and just call `ToList` or `ToArray` on the `Values` collection of the `Dictionary` when you specifically need to.

Comment: Shouldn't you call list.Remove before changing the dict[ID]? You're trying to remove the instance you've just created instead of the old one. There's no way the new instance is already on the list... I'm supposing ResourceBuildings is a class since you've said it can be null.

Comment: Do it differently. In the Dictionary, store <string,int> where int is an index into the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Short answer**

```
dict[ID] = new T
{
    ID = resBuilding.ID,
    hourlyIncome = resBuilding.hourlyIncome,
    baseHour = resBuilding.baseHour,
    incomeIncrement = resBuilding.incomeIncrement,
    totalSupply = resBuilding.totalSupply
};
list.RemoveAll(item => item.ID == ID);
list.Add(dict[ID]);
```

*Side note*: `dict[key] = value` is enough to create a new element with the specified key or update an existing one (see the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx)), so the whole `if (dict.ContainsKey(ID))` is pointless.

---

### **Extended answer**

Maybe this is a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), and your current approach could be hiding your real problem-to-be-solved (possibly: [*I want a dictionary-like structure that shows up in inspector*](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SerializableDictionary)).